# C# The "while" should break after someone put the correct answer in but it doesnt

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

I'm really new in programing this is actually my first program but I'm stuck at this problem for a day now.
The `while` repeats the same method the whole time, it doesn't matter if `letter1 == correct1` or not.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            string try1;
            char correct1 = 'o';
            string try2;
            string correct2 = "r";
            string try3;
            string correct3 = "a";
            string try4;
            string correct4 = "n";
            string try5;
            string correct5 = "g";
            string try6;
            string correct6 = "e";

            int live = 9;
            int letter = 6;

            Console.WriteLine("Hanging man");
            try1 = Console.ReadLine();
            char letter1 = try1[0];

            while ( letter1 != correct1 ||
                    try1 != correct2 || 
                    try1 != correct3 || 
                    try1 != correct4 || 
                    try1 != correct5 || 
                    try1 != correct6)
            {
                live--;
                Console.WriteLine("Schade leider ist der buchstabe " +
                                      try1 + " nicht dabei du hast noch " +
                                      live + " Leben ");
                Console.WriteLine("Versuch es erneut");
                try1 = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
```

Comment: `try1 != correct2 || try1 != correct3 || try1 != correct4 || try1 != correct5 || try1 != correct6` will always evaluate to true. Your string cannot possible have all these values at once. You want to use logical AND `&&`

Comment: You want to use a do...while, with a boolean "continue" variable. This is pretty much how I would do every "repeat input until the user starts making sense" routines. This condition is way to complicated for a single code line.

Comment: `true || true || false` and `true || false || true` and `false || true || true` all evaluate to `true`.

Comment: When you find yourself using 6 variables and handling them in the same way more or less, start thinking using a collection (e.g. `List<string>` or `List <char>` in your case): code will simplify a lot. Also note that: `correct1` is a `char` and other `correctX` are string (why?) and you are not using at all `try2...n`

Answer (score 1):

Boolean algebra: `!(a || b)` is equal `!a && !b` .
Try this:

```
while ( letter1 != correct1 && try1 != correct2 && try1 != correct3 && try1 != correct4 && try1 != correct5 && try1 != correct6)
```

Comment: What does "Boolean algebra: `!(a || b)` is equal `!a && !b`" have to do with this question? I get that it's close to the OP's problem, but it isn't what's going on here.

Comment: @Enigmativity The loop should break when any pair is equal. So one way to write the loop is to say `while (!(a==x || b==x || ...)` which is equivalent to `while (a!=x && b !=x && ...)`